# My switch case is not working, case is ending early

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, error-handling, switch-statement

After i choose 1 and enter the car color, program not asking the fallowing part, what should i do. Output is like this:
1.Add a car
2.Remove car
3.Display Car Information
4.Exit

1

Enter car color: black

Enter  car model year:
Enter  car model price:
Enter number of passengers for car:

```
case 1:

    cout << "\nEnter car color: ";
    cin >> c.color;

    cout << "\nEnter  car model year: ";
    cin >> c.modelyear;

    cout << "\nEnter  car model price: ";
    cin >> c.carprice;

    cout << "\nEnter number of passengers for car:   ";
    cin >> c.passengers;

    cout << "\nEnter car model (Sedan, SUV, Coupe, Station Wagon, Hatchback):    ";
    cin >> c.model;
```

Comment: Add `break;` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the declaration for your `c` struct, so I will speculate :)

The behavior is consistent with `c.color` being declared as `int`. When you type `black<Enter>`, the `cin` fails to convert it to an `int`, so it sets a `fail` bit (I believe). From that point on all subsequent `cin >>` operations will fail, until that bit is cleared.